# Register same class under multiple interfaces in PicoContainer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, picocontainer

I have next input:

1. PicoContainer instance configured next way:

```java
MutablePicoContainer pico = new PicoBuilder()
                .withLifecycle()
                .withCaching()
                .withConstructorInjection()
                .withSetterInjection()
                .withHiddenImplementations()
                .build();
```

The important thing that it uses hidden implementations.

2. The classes, let's say, structure:

```java
    interface A {

    }

    interface B {

    }

    public class AB implements A, B {
        public AB(/*dependencies on other components that exist in container*/) {

        }
    }
```

3. The problem:

I want to register same class instance in the context under those interfaces described before, something like this:

```java
pico.addComponent(A.class, AB.class);
pico.addComponent(B.class, pico.getComponent(A.class)); // cuses ClassCastException since proxy wrapper is used
```

The main idea is to initialize class instance usig existing context and do this only once (if it is possible in this case).

Please, help.

Comment: Caching container already provides singleton instances.

Comment: I know that, thanx. The question is not about this

Comment: I don't see the question actually, you described the problem, you've offered a solution (which is antipattern btw) but what's the question?